# How to filter results in nested relationships in django serializer?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am following following tutorial
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships
Here is my code.

```
class EmpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pass
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['name', 'dept', 'start_date', 'is_full_time']

class DeptCurrEmpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pass
    currEmployees = EmpSerializer(many=True, \
        queryset=Employee.objects.filter(is_full_time=True))
    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ['id']
```

I want to limit the DeptCurrEmpSerializer to limit the results to only the full_time employees. I get an error "unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'". Is there any other way I can do this. Eventually, the EmpSerializer itself will have an "ActiveTasks" serializer under it.

Comment: Yes, but not with the serialzier alone, you prefetch in the queryset of the view. Can you share the `ModelViewSet` (or another view)?

Comment: Couldn't respond you earlier. I just started on django-rest-framework and haven't reached Views part yet. I was trying this out in the shell. I have traditional template based views where I use the result of the Department.objects.get(id='XXXX') as a key and results of Employee.objects.filter(dept='XXXX').filter(is_full_time=True) as values in a dictionary as pass it to the view as a context variable. For now, all I want to see is a Department and it's full time employees serialized as a single item.